# How does Twitter official iOS app changes status bar with custom text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

[image]

The new official Twitter for iOS app changes statusbar just like in the picture above. How to implement such a feature?

[[image source](http://littlebigdetails.com/post/33363254165/twitter-ios-app-gives-feedback-in-the-status-bar)]

Comment: As an consumer of iOS apps, I don't like it when apps do this. The status bar is not part of the app; it's part of the system. Don't touch it; it's not yours to mess around with.  You've got a whole rest of the screen to come up with a creative UI.  Please leave that area alone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I do it in my app with a rotating animation:

```
-(void)showStatusBarMessage:(NSString *)message hideAfter:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    __block UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame];
    statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusWindow.bounds];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    label.text = message;
    [statusWindow addSubview:label];
    [statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    label.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5, 1, 0, 0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        label.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        double delayInSeconds = delay;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                label.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5, -1, 0, 0);
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                statusWindow = nil;
                [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] makeKeyAndVisible];
            }];
        });
    }];
}
```

I have it in a category on UIViewController to use it from whatever controller in the app.

**EDIT:** Needs `QuartzCore.framework` to be referenced and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to be added.

Comment: I actually wondered what was the logic behind that, can you please explain a little bit? Do they hide status bar and show theirs, or what?

Comment: Unless they tell how they do it, you can only assume how they do it.I only add a UIWindow instance on top hiding it, add a label to it, make the animation and then remove the window

Comment: Hi Moxy, it is working great, marked as correct answer but with the iOS 6, the status bar takes a similar color to app's navbar color. In this case, not exactly black. Is there a workaround you think?

Comment: You can set the background color to whatever color you want. Since you're the one to set the status bar color, just choose the background color that best suits your design.

Comment: How would I implement a different animation? (as in, maybe it drops in or just appears rather than the fade from top and bottom)